# Music Album Art stretched to square

Tags: album-art

My phone runs Android 4.0.4 and it has Google's "Play Music" and a stock "Music Player". For some reasons, either App shows album arts as square. Album arts that were rectangular are stretch to square. The same MP3s copied to other phones looks fine.

I checked the files under \Android\data\com.android.providers.media\albumthumbs\ and they are in the correct aspect ratio. I tried erasing the App data. But I just can't make the Album Arts look right. Any ideas?

Comment: You can't do anything about that because that's the way they work. There is no option to make any settings. Try music apps from Play Store but you may suffer from online ads.

Comment: I don't know about the stock player but the Play Music shows album art stretched to square but another phone (also 4.0.4) with the Play Music app does not suffer from the same problem.

Comment: I just tried downloading another 3rd party Music App "Music". I see the same behavior, the thumb nails are stretched to square. But during playback, it is fine. My guess is there is some sort of built-in library on my phone that is messed up.